# How to send different data to custom cells in the same UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5

This is for a blog app  and the issue I'm having is with the layout of the post and its comments.

Ideally the layout would be like this (version 1):

[image]

The parent is a UIScrollView, and all other elements you see are inside it. The UITabelView at the bottom receives the comment thread.

This works, but the problem is with the comments UITableView. I thought I could turn off its scrolling and have it "grow" vertically based on the number of comments. But after a few rows, the content gets clipped. That is because the remaining rows are not being rendered within the vertical size of the UIScrollView.

I've read in SO to do away with the UIScrollView - and instead build the whole thing in a UITableView. Create a custom cell on top to hold the UIImageView, another custom cell below for post text, etc.

**Version 2**

[image]

My question is: how do you send a specific portion of a JSON feed to populate custom cells, and then iterate through the comments populating the lower cells?

For example the code below sends/iterates comments to the comments UITableView in version 1.

But how would I send the post image or post text to the custom cells in version 2?

Is there a better approach? Any kind of advice is greatly appreciated.

**DetailViewController.h**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"commentCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *post           = self.detailItem;
    NSArray      *commentThread  = [post objectForKey:@"comment"];
    NSDictionary *comment        = [commentThread objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString     *commentText       = [comment objectForKey:@"comment_text"];
    NSString     *commentAuthorName = [comment objectForKey:@"comment_author_name"];

    cell.textLabel.text       = commentText;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = commentAuthorName;

    return cell;
}
```

**JSON**

```
...
{
    "post_id": "1463",
    "post_title": null,
    "post_text": "dffsdjdflkjklk dlfkjsdlfkj",
    "comment": [
        {
            "comment_author_name": "2162",
            "comment_text": "yuiyuiiopiop",
        },
        {
            "comment_author_name": "2163",
            "comment_text": "tyutyutyutyuu",
        },
        {
            "comment_author_name": "2164",
            "comment_text": "sdfsertertr",
        },
    ]
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put post text and image into tableViewHeader.

or put the post text and image in tableView section 0

put the comment in section 1

## Edit

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    //config the image view

    UILabel *postContentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];//or other UI component
    //Config the postContentLabel

    UIView *tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    [tableHeaderView addSubview:imageView];
    [tableHeaderView addSubview:postContentLabel];
    //set the tableHeaderView frame

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = tableHeaderView;
}
```

Comment: thanks @agassi_yzh - how would the code for that look like? any examples you know of?

Answer (score 0):

yeah it is correct either you simply use header view in table view i m putting the example 
take a view say headerView and have imageView in it
after response simply put the image in a imageview object
then load the table view like that

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return self.headerView;

} 

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  return 210;

}
```

then use the cellForRowAtIndexPath as you have used above .